# как сделать механику персонажу что бы он автоматически уклонялся от преград на пути

Tags: алгоритм, unreal-engine-4

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья , нужна подсказка - помощь с Unreal engine 4.
Начал делать игру , по концепции раннера , герой бежит вперед .
вопрос такой , может кто подсказать логику для персонажа , что бы он летел и автоматически уклонялся от преград на пути.
что то по типу (летит-видит преграды-считывает-огибает их). буду очень благодарен за помощь, всем добра)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: я конечно не назвал бы себя професиоаналом но попробуй сделать через line trase и включение анимации через anim montage https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/voxel-plugin-free#:~:text=Voxel%20Plugin%20brings%20state%2Dof,Engine%2C%20with%20well%20integrated%20features. видео про паркур но можеш код как пример брать отсюда